# UITabBar transparent labels bug in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, xcode11

iOS: 13.1.2
Xcode: 11.1 (11A1027)

In our tab bar we opted for using transparent text for the tab items, so in iPhone we only show the tab item image, while the text is invisible (and it should be only visible on iPad), we do this by calling:

```swift
extension UITabBarItem {
    func updateTitleVisibility(for traitCollection: UITraitCollection) {
        switch traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass {
        case .compact:
            hideTabBarTitle()
        default:
            showTabBarTitle()
        }
    }

    func hideTabBarTitle() {
        imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)
        setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .normal)
        setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .selected)
    }

    func showTabBarTitle() {
        imageInsets = .zero
        setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.licorice], for: .normal)
        setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.secondaryBlue], for: .selected)
    }
}
```

When compiling our app for iOS 13 (it didn’t happen on iOS 12), there is a strange behavior happening (notice the tab bar):

[Video of the bug @ Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvc2C.jpg)

(^ i didn't manage to embed it in the post)

[image: Imgur]

So the tab text sudden shows for the inactive tabs after presenting a full screen view controller, but incredibly enough when checking the view debugger *the labels that are supposed to be transparent are **indeed** transparent*

[image: view debugger]

**Has anybody seen a behavior like that? How can I fix it**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is due to the behavior in the default dark mode on iOS 13.

To achieve what you wanted with labels as on iOS versions below 13,

Simply add this into your Info.plist:

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

What this essentially does is changing the global user interface style to the light style which is the default style on iOS versions below 13.

If you won't prefer to change the user interface style, you can also  change the tint color of the unselected items on the tab bar:

```
tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = .darkGray
```

or to any other tint color of your choice.

Comment: I should have mentioned that, but since our app does not yet support dark mode, I added the **force light mode** setting in the info plist that you mentioned, yet the behavior still happens. The strange thing is that goes from not showing the labels to showing the labels (as shown in the video)

Comment: do you replace the whole tab bar or something like that? it's weird because the first two tabs work as expected and then all of a sudden they don't

Comment: just to try, I added the line `tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = .bgPrimary` to my tab bar controller and the bug doesn't appear anymore. It's not clear to me why, but this does work.